# AMP pages not redirecting in my Development site [Non-Wordpress]

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, iis, amp-html

I have added a new amp page for my existing page.

Below is the markup added in my original page

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://staging.example.com/blazor">

<link rel="amphtml" href="https://staging.example.com/blazor/amp">
```

Below is the markup added in my AMP page

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://staging.example.com/blazor">
```

But when i open my development site page (this page is excluded in **robots.txt** file) in mobile, the page is not redirecting to AMP page.

Do i need to add any redirection code for this behaviour or is this because my development site pages are not indexed in google ?

My site is hosted in **IIS**, and developed using **ASP.NET MVC Web Application**

Answer (score 1):

There is no automatic redirection going to happen. Your AMP page will start appearing in Google Search results after a few days once it has been indexed by GoogleBot.

You can use the [Google AMP Tester](https://search.google.com/test/amp) to check if everything is set up correctly and what it's going to look like in search result.